# Error using Interface "Object not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Hi I have following line in my code that keeps giving me an error "Object not set to an instance of an object" I tried different things but nothing seems to shake it off. I will appreciate idea why it is doing that.

```
  IEmailCallback  cb=OperationContext.Current.Getchannel<IEmailCallback>
```

Comment: Presumably `OperationContext.Current` is null.  Are you possibly using threads?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: To help see which object is null, set a breakpoint on that line and use the debugger to see what is null.